# При обращение к View каждый раз срабатывает get{} у свойств

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пытаюсь разобраться с анимацией в MVVM.
Условно имеется 2 `View`.
Во второй `View` в `UserControl.Resources` имеется 2 `Storyboard`. `sbSidePanelShow` и `sbSidePanelHide`

Для запуска анимации использую `Trigger`

```
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSidePanelOn}" Value="True" >
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource sbSidePanelShow}"  ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
                </ei:DataTrigger>
                <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSidePanelOn}" Value="False">
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource sbSidePanelHide}"   ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
                </ei:DataTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Меняя значения **IsSidePanelOn** запускается та или иная анимация.

**Проблема:**

Переходя на `View` где анимации - она автоматически проигрывается со значение которые находится в `IsSidePanelOn`, то есть идет обращение к методу get у свойства IsSidePanelOn

```
public bool IsSidePanelOn
{
    get{ return _isSidePanelOn;}
    set { _isSidePanelOn = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
} I
```

Класс `View2` статичный, создается при запуске программы.

Comment: ну а что вы ожидаете, если вы биндите представление на это свойство?

Comment: @tym32167 Я не до конца понимаю почему оно повторно срабатывает при обращении к View, возможно это и должно так работать. Тогда получается, что анимацию в данном случае прикручивать только к кнопке?